# Animation for a Component

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I know there is an **Ext.Fx.Anim** in Ext JS 4.0 and it is missing in Ext JS 3.4. Just wanted to know if there are any workarounds in getting some basic (say ease in) animation for a **Component** in Ext JS 3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do it for a component that is not in a managed layout. If that is true, you can animate the `Ext.Element` that wraps your content by calling `Ext.Component.getEl()`

```
var panel =  new Ext.Panel({html: 'My content'});
// Or any method defined in http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Fx
panel.getEl().slideIn();
```

Comment: So, if I want to slideIn a toolbar when I hover over a container, do I need to inject html manually?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I didn't say anything about injecting HTML manually. If you want a toolbar to slide in, you create and render the toolbar to the body, then you call toolbar.getEl().slideIn(). Now if you want it to be added to a layout, you'll have to get creative; that is, you need append it to its parent container after you finish the slide in.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.4, you have Ext.Fx class, which is applied, automatically by the framework, to Ext.Element. So, every element, by default, has the animation support. And with this, the methods that you see in Ext.Fx are also available on you element, like - highlight, fadeIn, slideIn, etc.

Comment: Two things missing here: You can't just animate Components, you have to call `Ext.Component.getEl()` and animate that. Second, if your component is part of a layout, the positioning sizing of the Component is handled by the LayoutManager, therefore, you need to be very careful with animating something that is not under your control. But hey, try it out, I hope it works.